# Disable screen orientation change on facebook web login dialog

Tags: android, facebook, screen-orientation

I have a facebook login feature on my app. Now my problem is, I don't want to give the ability to change screen orientations on the facebook web login dialog because when the screen orientation changes, the facebook web login dialog starts again and it's annoying sometimes for the user. Before this was fixed when I was suppressing the sso feature of the facebook login. But when I utilize it, this issue comes back again. I thought maybe this is related on how I restrict my app to be on portrait only.

Here's how I'm doing it in my manifest.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

I've done a lot of research and this is what I have now in my manifest.

Note: I'm not really sure if by removing the SUPRESS SSO on my auth button causes this issue to appear. But as I said, when I was SUPRESSING SSO login before, this issue was not present. Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change orientation just for that particular moment?

You could do this:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

**EDIT:**

OR, you could prevent the device from rotating like this:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```